# Unable to run websites on local IIS

Tags: iis, application-pool, http-status-code-503

I have a sneaky suspicion that this problem is related to a recent Windows Update. I keep getting `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` when I try to run websites locally on my development workstation. If I try to debug from Visual Studio 2017 I get

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote
>   server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

When I look at the application pool in IIS Manager, it is stopped. I restart it, but it eventually stops by itself.

In the Windows Application log, I have this:

> The worker process for application pool 'DefaultAppPool' encountered
>   an error 'Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read
>   configuration data from file `'\\?\<EMPTY>'`, line number '0'.  The data
>   field contains the error code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the temporary symbolic links created for the application pools by IIS/WAS being messed up during the Windows Update process for installing Fall Creators Update.

I found the solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1260805/iis-10-cannot-read-empty-configuration-file/1260834?